# Does this graph contain $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as subdivision or minor?

Tags: graph-theory

Does this graph contain subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$?

Does this graph contain  $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as minor?

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm correct, but I think the answer is yes for both questions. $K_5$ has 5 vertices of degree 4, this graphs has 6 of them, and $K_{3,3}$ has 6 vertices of degree 3, and this graph also has 5 of them. are these enough to conclude that this graph says $G$ contain both $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ as subdivision and minor?

Comment: If that reasoning works, then it ought to be impossible to draw a planar graph that has 5 vertices of degree 4 and 6 vertices of degree 3. Have you tried to play around a bit to see whether that can really be the case?

Comment: Although I've never seen any planar that have 5 degree 4 vertices and 6 degree 3 vertices, but I also have the same doubt as yours because I can't say there isn't any just because I haven't seen it, that's why I'm not so sure about my reasoning. To determine subdivision and minor, I always count the cycle first, then check the vertices and their degree. I wonder if there is better way to check?

Comment: x @Diane: Well, go ahead and try making one.

Comment: That reasoning is not enough, as you can draw a tree with as many vertices of degree 3 and 4 as you want, yet it remains planar.

Comment: I can see a $K_{3,3}$ straight off.... I strongly suspect there is no $K_5$ But your count of vertex degrees doesn't determine either matter.

Comment: @Joffan: your reply is the only one here that really addresses the problem. I agree with you, make your reply an answer.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk - done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the outer vertices clockwise $A,B,C,D,E,F$, the inner vertices $A',B',C',D',E',F'$
(starting at the same ray from the center).
Now there is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ having one partite set $A,C',E$ and the other $A',C,F$.
The connections are

$AA'$, $ABC$, $AF$

$C'A'$, $C'C$, $C'F'F$

$EE'A'$, $EDC$, $EF$

Comment: I'm sorry for keep asking question, but if the vertices you list above is the vertices of $K_{3,3}$ then should $C$ and $A$ be adjacent directly? Why have $B$ between them? Did you contract $BC$?

Comment: $A$ is in one partite set, $C$ is in the other. The subdivided edge between them is $ABC$. We just need to find a subdivided $K_{3,3}$, so the vertices that are adjacent in the $K_{3,3}$ need not be adjacent in the subdivision.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the six inner vertices as $A,B,C,D,E,F$ in anticlockwise order. Denote the outer vertices as $A',B',C',D',E',F'$ accordingly.

Let's try subdivision of $K_5$: To find such, we need five vertices of degree (at least) $4$. Since there are six such vertices, we have littel choice. In fact, by symmetry, all possible choices are the same, so we may pick $A,B,C,D,E$. Then to exhibit a subdivision, we need to have a path from each of these vertices to each other vertex - and these paths must be vertex-disjoint (apart from the end points)!
Since the vertices are only of degree $4$, we must use all edges originating from our chosen vertices. This already completes $6$ of our needed $10$ paths: $AC, AD, AE, BD, BE, CE$. 
Of the paths from $C$ to $B$ and from $C$ to $D$, one must make use of $C'$ and one must ake use of $F$.
Then for the path from $A$ to $B$ we must take  $AA'B'B$ because $F$ is already used.  Similarly we have $EE'D'D$. But then the path from $C$ to $B$ or $D$ that goes via $C$ cannot be comppleted.  We conclude that this graph does *not* contain a subdivision of $K_5$ as subgraph.

Comment: The other three options do exist, though.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of vertices of degree $4$ or $3$ is not sufficient.  Consider the below graph with two concentric circles and a zigzag between them.  Each vertex has degree $4$ and there are $12$ of them.  This graph is planar, so includes neither $K_6$, nor $K_{3,3}$

[image]

Comment: What makes you say this graph is planar?

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk: Ross is not saying that the graph depicted in the question is planar, but that the one he has just described is.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: I see, thanks. I got off track because this is presented as an answer.

Comment: @Leen: It does answer the question at the very end of the OP.

Comment: Also known as an antiprism :-)

Answer (score 1):

---

*Subgraphs...*

I think I can see a $K_{3,3}$ straight off.... I strongly suspect from a casual viewing that there is no $K_5$. But your count of vertex degrees doesn't determine either matter.

If you can find 5 vertices of degree 4 that are linked, you have a $K_5$ - otherwise not. However in this case you can first (and iteratively) discard any vertices that  are degree 3 or below. The first pass of discarding low-degree vertices removes the outer ring, and the second pass leaves an empty graph - there is no $K_5$.

$K_{3,3}$ requires cycles of length 4, which the outer ring vertices do not have, so discard them....  Then inner six vertices do *not* form $K_{3,3}$, they form a triangular prism - I was mistaken earlier.

---

So much for my foray into subgraphs, which I think I mistakenly wandered into based on the vertex degree discussion. The question actually asked about subdivision or minor, for which counting vertex degree is even more irrelevant.

---

*Minors*

As Henning correctly points out, the graph has a minor of $K_6$ - which can be formed by contracting the 6 edges between the outer ring and the inner figure - and so also contains minors of $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$.

---

*Subdivisions*

The graph does contain subdivisions of $K_{3,3}$. These can can be produced by deleting two opposite nodes from the outer ring and smoothing out the other outer-ring nodes. There are also two inner-figure edges to remove to get to $K_{3,3}$. Hagen's answer demonstrates that there is no subdivision of $K_5$ in this graph.

Comment: quick question, in order to have $K_{3,3}$ there must be 3 vertices on the same partie that not adjacent to each other, but for the inner 6 vertices, I can't see how it can't form $K_{3,3}$ . Do you have to delete any edge?

Comment: I agreed with your comment that there is a $K_{3,3}$ subdivision. Unfortunately I don't understand your arguments here. Care to explain?

Comment: You seem to be looking for subgraphs instead of minors and subdivisions. That's not what the problem asks for. There's a $K_6$ minor, and therefore $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$ minors too.

Answer (score -1):

the answer is yes. For more defails see following literature:
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~mwilliams/pdf/petersen.pdf

Comment: This is not the Petersen graph!

Comment: My bad. I see now.